# Startup script always crashing on ubuntu 9.10 server edition

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, runlevel

I wrote a startup script that starts at startup for ubuntu 9.10 server edition and does the rsync of my  directories that is specified in my path, I did the startup in the old fashion way linking my script from init.d and placing it on run level, which is working and so i am able to start it on startup but after a while the service of my script is not running. It crashes on the middle after 5 minutes when the system is up and the code inside the script is just a line of rsync which i am sure is not the problem and so i have to invoke the script again to start it services? what is wrong with this? Can anyone help??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your `/var/log/` directory for log entries -- I don't know [`upstart`](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/index.html) nearly as well as I should, but I hope it would kill any `/etc/init.d/rc*` task that runs for five minutes. init scripts should use `start-stop-daemon` to start specific programs that run for a long time. (That way, those same programs can be gracefully shut down at reboot or shutdown time.) But the scripts themselves should run in under a second or so.

I'd suggest writing an actual `upstart` management script and placing it into `/etc/init/` instead of fighting with an init script. I don't think `upstart` is going away :) so you might as well get used to it.

Comment: well ya i have a start-stop-restart-status daemon, but the thing during the startup it starts and the service will be running if i check the status but after few minuted the service goes down, that is my concerned, why is it doing so?

Comment: catvsrat: I think what sarnold is trying to say is - perhaps because the rsync takes more than the upstart time limit for service starting, then it kills it before it manages to complete.

Comment: oh ok but i recently realized that my script fails only when i make some changes on the path specified for the rsync, very weired, any guess ?

Comment: @catvsrat, @sinelaw explained it perfectly -- and the path difference could be the time difference between upstart assuming the task is being performed correctly and assuming the task has hung and should be killed. Please note that `start-stop-daemon` is a specific tool, and `start-stop-restart-daemon` does not exist. I hope that was just a typo on your part ;) but if it isn't, I suggest learning about `start-stop-daemon` if you intend to keep this script an initscript, rather than rewrite it as an upstart task. Any luck with logging the output as @sinelaw recommended?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough information to solve your problem, but I suggest you pipe rsync's stderr into a log file and try to figure out what went wrong. Try turning on '-v' for verbosity too. For example:

```
rsync ...blabla... -v 2>&1  | cat > /tmp/rsync.log
```

Or so.

Comment: Also, try running rsync with the exact same parameters (and permissions) manually from the shell and see what happens.

Comment: That's a *big* UUoC! Try `rsync ... 2> /tmp/rsync.log` or `rsync ... > /tmp/rsync.log 2>&1`.